# Fortigate 50B - Configuration

Tags: networking, router

I have fiber coming in and being handed off via Ethernet. I am having trouble configuring the router (Fortigate 50b (recommended by one of our vendors)). It looks like it can be configured in NAT/Router and transparent modes but from how I understand the info I was given by the service provider (XO/TimeWarner) I can't determine how to set the settings.

I have two sets of IP's. "LAN Block" which contains ....

```
Customer LAN Block XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX//28
Customer Gateway XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Useable Range: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Customer Subnet 255.255.255.240
```

Pretty straight forward. The IP's are public IP's provided by the service provider.

I then I have another set "wan" that only has...

```
Wan Block XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/30
WAN Subnet 255.255.255.252
Network Side XXX.XXx.XXX.XXX
Customer Side XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Notice there is no gateway. Also the "customer lan block" are public IP's. I don't understand how to connect these two networks. In the router setup seems my only options are transparent and "NAT/ROUTER". Transparent definitely isn't what i want since in this mode I lose the ability to configure anything IP wise. I am also pretty sure i don't want NAT. I am getting spun around the axle so any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You would set the gateway to the network side for the WAN set of IPs.

Unfortunately, looking at the documentation:
http://docs.fortinet.com/fgt.html#
it doesn't appear that you can actually *disable* NAT when routing.  I guess this is more of an "appliance" than a router.  I'm not sure why this product was advised.